# Differentiable function exercise

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Regarding:

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, $f'$ is increasing, and $f(0)=0$.

Prove that for every $x>0$ we have $\frac{f(x)}{x} \le f'(x)$.

--

I have tried many things, like showing that $f'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$, I have tried using monotone of limits, toast, showing that $0 \le f''$, looking at thorems like Darboux, Ferma, Rolle....

Unfortunately I do not know what to do with "$f'$ is increasing".

Please, if someone can only give me a **hint** I will very appreciate that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Let $ x>0$.

By MVT, there exists $ c\in (0,x) $ such that

$$f(x)-f(0)=(x-0)f'(c)\le xf'(x)$$
because $ f'$ is increasing.

Comment: I think I got it!
By MVT, there exists $c_{x}$ such that $0<c_{x}<x$ such as: $f'(c_{x})=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)}{x}$, and because $f'$ is increasing, and we know that $c_{x}<x$, than $f'(c_{x})<f(x)$, so $\frac{f(x)}{x} \le f'(x)$, is that correct?

Comment: @MathLover Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Consider $$\int_0^1 f'(tx)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t.$$